# PHP import DAT File into MySQL - First line is not inserted

Tags: php, mysql

I have a working code that imports DAT file contents to a table in MySQL. Everything is okay except it does not insert the first row. I want all rows to be inserted on the table. The DAT File contains a base64 encoded data using powershell. My PHP Code below decodes the base64 and inserts all contents to my MySQL Table except the first row. For this example, I displayed the insert statement instead of inserting to MySQL so you may be able to test without using mysql.

```
<?php
 $dat_perm_loc="94-20161223.DAT";
 $dtrfile = file_get_contents($dat_perm_loc);
                $clean_dtrfile = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-=]/', '', $dtrfile);
                $decoded_data= base64_decode($clean_dtrfile);
                $dtrfile = fopen($dat_perm_loc, 'w');
                fwrite($dtrfile, $decoded_data);
                fclose($dtrfile);
                $csv_file = $dat_perm_loc;
                if (($handle = fopen($csv_file, "r")) !== FALSE) {
                   fgetcsv($handle);
                   while (($data = fgetcsv($handle)) !== FALSE) {
                                $num = count($data);
                                for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
                                  $col[$c] = $data[$c];
                                }
                                        $data = preg_split('/\s+/', $col[0]);
                                        $comp=$col[0];
                                        $empbio=$data[0];
                                        $dtr_date=$data[1];
                                        $dtr_time=$data[2];
                                        $in_or_out=$data[4];
                                //display the data to be insert in the DB
                                echo "insert into rfc_bio_dtr (data,extdtrcid,dtr_date,dtr_time,in_or_out,empbio,branchtype,branchname) values ('$comp','1','$dtr_date','$dtr_time','$in_or_out','$empbio','2','3'); <br/>";
                 }
                        fclose($handle);
                }

?>
```

Here is the contents of 94-20161223.DAT file:

```
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
```

Please note that my DAT file is a TAB Delimited file. once decoded. If you want to see the decoded file first before firing the code below. Open this to notepad++ and decode the base64 using mime tools

Comment: The first `fgetcsv($handle);` before the loop reads the first row. The next rows are read and "inserted into `rfc_bio_dtr`" in the loop.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I mean that the first row is not inserted because it is consumed by the first call to `fgetcsv`. The first row is unused, in other words.

Comment: Just remove or comment out the first `fgetcsv($handle);`